# Advice on searching for availability in MSSql using VB

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I would appreciate a little advice on the most appropriate method for managing bookings.

I am adding to an existing program, written in VB with an MSSql DB.

I am currently using win forms as the GUI, utilising a DataGridView to display the data with a Month control.

My current DB schema is:

```
bikeDetail (bikeID (PK), bikeName, bikeColour, bikeStyle, bikeNotes)

bikeMovements (bikeMovementID (PK), bikeID, customerID, bikeMovementType, bikeMovementDate, bikeMovementAMPM, bikeMovementNotes).

customer (customerID, ..., ...)
```

The idea is that each time a  bike is taken in or out, a record is made in the bikeMovements database.  This may not be the easiest way of saving this data, but it should hopefully mean the database won't get bloated with  lots of repeated data.

My problem is that I am struggling to work out the best way to search through the bikeMovements table in order to find out if bikes are in or out, and are hence available to book out.  Using the calendar tool I am able to select a range of dates.

So far, I have been able to work out if a  bike is available on a certain date by using a sql query, but not for the range of dates.

Current sql query:

```
    SELECT * FROM tb_bikeMovements as bm, tb_bikeDetail as bd
    WHERE bm.bikeMovementDate < '" + startDate + "'
    and bm.bikeID = bd.bikeID
    and bm.bikeMovementType = 1
```

This returns the bikes that are available from that day onward. (bikeMovementType 1 is the bike coming back in, and hence is available).

I would appreciate any advice on either a better sql query for bringing back availability, or a better way to setup the DB that would make querying it simpler.

Example dates:

bike 1 goes out on 22 April, and is booked back in for 24 April (available from 25 April) 
bike 2 goes out on 22 April, and is booked back in for 28 April (available from 29 April) 
bike 3 goes out on 26 April, and is booked back in for 27 April (available from 28 April) 
bike 4 is available from 22 April onward.

What bikes are available for 25 - 29 April?  (should be bike 1 and 4.  Catching bike 1 is easy, bike 3 is the fly in the ointment as it goes out and back in within the selected date range!).

I am thinking that the easiest way would be to change my DB schema so that a record is created for every day that a bike is booked out for.  This will make it a lot easier to search for availability, but will make the table way more bloated (2 records for each bike hire currently, in and out), with a record for every day the bike is out.  To be fair though, we are not yet sure how many days these bikes will be rented for, and this would have an impact on my decision.

Any advice will be gratefully received!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly then  a bike is not available if there is a movement record (either out or in) in the required date range ( it is available the day after it is returned )
it is also not available if the last movement record was out

the query

```
select distinct bikeid from bikemovements where bikeMovementDate between '25 April 2013' and '29 April 2013'
```

would give bikes that moved in or out between the 25 to 29 April

so we can negate this by using "not in" to find the available bikes

```
select * from bikeDetail where bikeid not in (
  select distinct bikeid from bikemovements where bikeMovementDate between '25 April 2013' and '29 April 2013'
)
```

But I guess we should also check if a bike is booked out already and has not come in

this will get the last movement day for each bike ( up to the start date)

```
  select bikeid bid, max(bikemovementdate) bmd from bikemovements
  where bikemovementdate < '25 April 2013' 
  group by bikeid) lastmove
```

and to look up the movement record we could

```
select * from bikemovements join 
(
  select bikeid, max(bikemovementdate) bmd from bikemovements
  where bikemovementdate < '25 April 2013' 
  group by bikeid
) lastmove 
on lastmove.bikeid=bikemovements.bikeid and 
   lastmove.bmd=bikemovements.bikemovementdate
```

to find only the ones with last movement of out

```
select bikemovements.bikeid from bikemovements join 
(
  select bikeid, max(bikemovementdate) bmd from bikemovements
  where bikemovementdate < '25 April 2013' 
  group by bikeid) lastmove 
on lastmove.bikeid=bikemovements.bikeid and 
   lastmove.bmd=bikemovements.bikemovementdate
where bikeMovementType = 'out'
```

so putting it all together we could have something along the lines of

```
select * from bikeDetail where bikeid not in (
select distinct bikeid from bikemovements 
  where bikeMovementDate between '25 April 2013' and '28 April 2013'
  ) 
and bikeid not in ( 

select bikemovements.bikeid from bikemovements join 
(
  select bikeid, max(bikemovementdate) bmd from bikemovements 
  where bikemovementdate < '25 April 2013' 
  group by bikeid
) lastmove 
 on lastmove.bikeid=bikemovements.bikeid and 
   lastmove.bmd=bikemovements.bikemovementdate
 where bikeMovementType = 'out'
)
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ba19d/11/0)

Comment: Hi Ian, awesome response speed, many thanks! Unfortunately this doesn't catch bike 2, which is out for the duration of the selected dates, and I can't work out why...

Comment: I did try out in [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ba19d/8/0) and it only returned bikes 1 and 4

Comment: I got it, the checking a bike is out should only look at dates before the start date - i will edit the answer

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks Ian, and I am just about able to understand it as well :)

Comment: Hi again Ian, I have come up against a bit of a problem, the sql query there means that any bike booked out for one day is not showing as available for any day after that.  I have amended the sql fiddle to add the bike going in and out on 25th, and the query is asking for bikes available on 26th and it is not picking that bike up (bike id 6)  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b630b/3.  If you could advise, I would be very grateful!

Comment: I think if you stored a date and time (rather than a date) the query would work [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f1036/2/0) is this possible ?

Comment: I think you are right, I am amending my code this morning.  Thank you :)